# how to browse all the documents of a mongo database to modify a field in js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm working on a database migration script from one environment to another and I want to change the value of the fields of some data by concatenating ".test" at the end.

I use a js script withe the dependencies "mongodb": "3.3.1" to make some changes and I want to add this feature.

```
MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${host}:${port}`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then((client) => {
    const db = client.db(database);
    updateField(db, 'TableName')
});

function updateField(db, name) {

    db.collection(name)
        .find({})
        .foreach(function (doc) {
            if (doc.val != null) {
                return
            }
            const newValue = doc.val + ".test";
            db.collection(name)
                .updateOne(
                    {_id: doc._id},
                    {$set: {"val": newValue}}
                )
        }
}
```

I expect all field val have the new value val+".test" in the table 'TableName'.

I don't know why the code in the foreach loop is never execute.

Comment: Please update `foreach` to be camel case `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

Please update `foreach` to be `forEach` also I'm wondering why you return if `value != null` , do you want to change nullable values only or, as you mentioned in the question you want to change some fields which have some data.

Your code will update nullable values only and add.test to it.

If You want to change some certain values You can add this values in array and filter the results by $in operator, it will eliminate the other documents.

```
 db.collection(name)
    .find({val :   { "$in" : ["abc","aaa"]}    }).
       forEach(function (doc) {

        const newValue = doc.val + ".test";
        db.collection(name)
            .updateOne(
                {_id: doc._id},
                {$set: {"val": newValue}}
            ) ;
     })
```